# Flat spline for curves

Tags: template

Surely it's possible to use a [flat spline](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_spline) to draw (and even jigsaw or route) an arbitrary smooth curve.

What are some guidelines for doing this?

What material for the curve? What to use for ducks? Is it possible to use a router with  a guided bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some tricks to draw long arcs along a table apron](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/what-are-some-tricks-to-draw-long-arcs-along-a-table-apron)

Comment: Assume you mean the bent-stick version in that (unfortunately confounded) Wiki link? If so the above link is highly related. Ducks?? No you can't use one directly with a router (flex in use, control points get in the way). You'd use one to do your layout on what will become a template, then cut, smooth as much as needed and then you use that for routing.